# VBA Calling Public Sub in Worksheet Module: Crosstalk between Sheet and ThisWorkbook modules

Tags: vba, excel

I was so pleased that this works that I thought I would share it...

It allows me to have generic event handlers in the `ThisWorkbook` module to initiate worksheet-specific code in an anonymous `ActiveSheet`.

I use the `CalByName` function to access user-defined, Public methods in the Sheet objects.

I'm using it to re-start a timer that is killed by auto-recover saves and it works great.  I've got it on two sheets.

In `ThisWorkbook`  Module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    On Error GoTo afterSaveFailed
    CallByName ws, "afterSave", VbMethod
    If debugEvents Then Debug.Print timeStamp & ": " & "AfterSave: afterSave called in sheet: " & ws.Name
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
afterSaveFailed:
    If debugEvents Then Debug.Print timeStamp & ": " & "AfterSave: afterSave Failed in sheet: " & ws.Name
    Err.Clear
End Sub
```

then in each applicable Worksheet Module:

```
Public Sub afterSave()
    'sheet specific after save handler
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`CallByName` is a very old and well known method. :)

Also in your code

1. What is `debugEvents` You might want to use `Option Explicit`
2. Why `_AfterSave` and not `_BeforeSave`? What if `afterSave()` makes a change to the workbook? You will have to save again before closing.

Also instead of pasting the code in each applicable worksheet and creating duplicate code why not create a common code in a module?

```
Public Sub afterSave(oWs as Worksheet)
    With oWs
        'sheet specific after save handler
    End With
End Sub
```

**Worst Case Scenario**:

Assuming that the `afterSave` is different for every worksheet. You could always use a `Select Case`. This will ensure that you have your code in one place. You don't have to hop around to check the code.

```
Public Sub afterSave(oWs As Worksheet)
    With oWs
        Select Case .Name

        Case "AAA"

        Case "BBB"

        Case "CCC", "DDD" '<~~ If two or more worksheet have the same code

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually it could be above or below depending which tab you select, but anyway... I'm sure you can figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the comments. My responses are inserted below:

> CallByName is a very old and well known method. :)

Which is why I didn't entitle the post "`CallByName`".

If you read the title, thats what its about.  I couldn't find a solution to this on the web so I had to figure out my own method.  My point is not about `CallByName`, its about cross-talk between the modules and using `CallByName` to maximum effect to achieve this, I'm not suggesting that `CallByName` is novel.
I guess I could achieve the same thing using `RaiseEvents` but I think maybe this is more straight-forward.

I was just happy coz VBA was letting me do what I wanted for a change :q

> Also in your code
>
> ```
> What is debugEvents You might want to use Option Explicit
> ```

It's a global flag to control how noisy the immediate window is. Yes I always use option explicit and do so in this case.  I assume that's a given.

> ```
> Why _AfterSave and not _BeforeSave? What if afterSave() makes a change to the workbook? You will have to save again before closing.
> ```

Because the stuff I'm doing needs to be done after the save has completed, not before it starts.  The `Autorecovery` save event kills a timer that I'm running so I need to re-start it after the save.

> Also instead of pasting the code in each applicable worksheet and
>   creating duplicate code why not create a common code in a module?
>
> Public Sub afterSave(oWs as Worksheet)
>       With oWs
>           'sheet specific after save handler
>       End With End Sub
>
> Worst Case Scenario:

Because its "sheet specific"

> Assuming that the afterSave is different for every worksheet. You
>   could always use a Select Case. This will ensure that you have your
>   code in one place. You don't have to hop around to check the code.
>
> Public Sub afterSave(oWs As Worksheet)
>       With oWs
>           Select Case .Name
>
> ```
>     Case "AAA"
>
>     Case "BBB"
>
>     Case "CCC", "DDD" '<~~ If two or more worksheet have the same code
>
> End With End Sub
> ```

OK, I'll think about that: thanks for the suggestion :)

When I have generic features, I prefer to handle that with `Class Modules`.  To me that's neater: I just instance the object in the sheet to expose the generic features, and as in your suggestion, I only have to check it once.  I also use the `Class_Initialize` and `Class_Terminate` events to transparently manage life cycle of the generic features. I couldn't do that with generic code in the `ThisWorkbook` object.

Thats how I handle general functionality, for object-specific features, my preference is to collect the code that is specific to the object, in the actual object: I prefer shy objects.  There's really no need to expose that detail to supervisory code. Also, if I'm working on the sheet, I don't have to skip back to a general module and I don't have to try and remember where I put the code or invent some convention, coz it's right there in sheet.

Thank you very much for taking the time to respond in detail!